# PyGame detecting collisions even though they are not happening

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I want to make a Snake game in Python but when I want to detect collision with rects, it seems the game detects collisions even though they are not happening:

```
if snake_rect.colliderect(jablko_rect):
   print("Mniam!")
```

This collision check prints out text infinitely. How can it print out text when obviously these 2 separate objects are not touching each other. It's not a while loop problem I think. The collision check is for the images which are 49 x 49 px
The whole code:

```
import random
import pygame
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
SZEROKOSC = 800
WYSOKOSC = 600
plansza = pygame.display.set_mode((SZEROKOSC, WYSOKOSC))  # rozmiar okna gry
pygame.display.update()
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")  # tytuł okna gry

KROK = 25  # o ile "kroków" ma się przemieszczać snake
snake = pygame.image.load("snake_element.png").convert()  # nasz snake
jablko = pygame.image.load("apple.png").convert()  # nasze jabłko
snake_rect = snake.get_rect()
jablko_rect = jablko.get_rect()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

czcionka = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)


def wiadomosc(msg, color):
    wiad = czcionka.render(msg, True, color)
    plansza.blit(wiad, [SZEROKOSC / 2 - 100, WYSOKOSC / 2 - 25])


def petla_gry():
    przegrana = False
    zamkniecie = False

    x1 = SZEROKOSC / 2  # koordynaty
    y1 = WYSOKOSC / 2  # koordynaty

    x1_zmiana = 0
    y1_zmiana = 0

    jablko_x = round(random.randrange(0, SZEROKOSC - 25) / 25.0) * 25.0  # 25 to połowa rozmiaru naszych obrazków
    jablko_y = round(random.randrange(0, WYSOKOSC - 25) / 25.0) * 25.0  # 25 to połowa rozmiaru naszych obrazków

    print(jablko_x)
    print(jablko_y)

    while not przegrana:
        while zamkniecie:
            plansza.fill(white)
            wiadomosc("Przegrałeś! Q - wyjście z gry, C - restart gry", (255, 0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        przegrana = True
                        zamkniecie = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        petla_gry()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                przegrana = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    x1_zmiana = -KROK
                    y1_zmiana = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    x1_zmiana = KROK
                    y1_zmiana = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    x1_zmiana = 0
                    y1_zmiana = -KROK
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    x1_zmiana = 0
                    y1_zmiana = KROK

        if x1 >= SZEROKOSC or x1 <= 0 or y1 >= WYSOKOSC or y1 <= 0:
            przegrana = True
            wiadomosc("Przegrałeś!", (255, 0, 0))
            pygame.display.update()
            sleep(2)

        x1 += x1_zmiana
        y1 += y1_zmiana

        plansza.fill((255, 255, 255))

        plansza.blit(snake, (x1 - 25, y1 - 25))  # 25 to połowa rozmiaru naszych obrazków
        plansza.blit(jablko, (jablko_x, jablko_y))
        pygame.display.update()

        if snake_rect.colliderect(jablko_rect):
            print("Mniam!")

        '''if x1 == jablko_x and y1 == jablko_y:
            print("Mniam!")'''

        clock.tick(8)  # czas odświeżania - ruch snake'a

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

petla_gry()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, but it returns a rectangle that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position.
The *Surface* is placed at a position on the display with the `blit` function.

You've to set the location of the rectangle,, e.g:

```py
snake_rect.topleft = (x1 - 25, y1 - 25)
jablko_rect.topleft = (jablko_x, jablko_y)
if snake_rect.colliderect(jablko_rect):
    print("Mniam!")
```